# Dynamic Aspect Ratio in Unity (for Anti-Aliasing)

Tags: unity, hdrp

I am using HDRP with 1920x1080 resolution. The anti-aliasing works very well if the screen resolution increases and it works really bad if the screen resolution is lower than 1920x1080. Why does this happen? Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Can you show us some examples of the bad output you're getting when your resolution is lower than 1920x1080? Contrasting against the desired look at full res helps too.

Comment: It might also be relevant to know which anti-aliasing algorithm you are using. Some algorithms can look weird under some circumstances.